# Jquery Toggle two function not work in 1.10.1

Tags: jquery, toggle

Jquery Toggle two function not work in jquery 1.10.1 but work's on Jquery 1.8.3

**HTML**

```
<p>For example, consider the HTML:</p>
                <div id="target">
                  Click here
                </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#target').toggle(function() {
    alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
});
```

and expmple is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chavdamalde/TjVdb/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Dude it doesn't works in jQuery 1.10.1

Still there is another way to do it...

```
$(function () {
    function first() {
       //Code for first time click goes here
        $(this).one("click", second);
    }
    function second() {
        //Code for second time click goes here
        $(this).one("click", first);
    }
    $("#target").one("click", first);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

[**jQuery.toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been deprecated since version 1.8 and removed sometime later. You can write your own implementation instead:

```
function handler1() {
    alert("first handler for .toggle() called.");
    $(this).one("click", handler2);
}
function handler2() {
    alert("second handler for .toggle() called.");
    $(this).one("click", handler1);
}
$("#target").one("click", handler1);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aXyQL/)

Answer (score 6):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TjVdb/3/)

[**DEMO jQuery 2.x (edge)**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TjVdb/4/)

use this `clickToggle` plugin as `toggle` function is removed from version 1.9

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function (func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function () {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('#target').clickToggle(function () {
    alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function () {
    alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This format was [removed in version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed), so you cannot use it - if you want this logic can be manually implemented or you can make use of the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

to include the migration plugin, after the inclusion of jQuery library add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: any other function for use this

Answer (score 0):

It was removed in jQuery 1.9:

> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions"
>   signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the
>   visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated. The
>   former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential
>   for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used
>   to restore the functionality.

Complete upgrade guide: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic method, with multiple functions to toggle:

```
var toggleFunctions = [
    function () { /* do something */},
    function () { /* do something else */},
    ...
    function () { /* do some other stuff*/}
];

$("#target").on("click", function(){
    // returns first function from array
    var currentFunction = toggleFunctions.shift(); 
    // executes the function
    currentFunction(); 
    // pushes current function to the back
    toggleFunctions [] = currentFunction; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

toggle is not working for me in jquery so with the help of stackoverflow 
my alternative is

```html
<a href="#" id="thiclik"> Click Me To Change</a>
  
  <div id="clickevent">
  </div>
```

and here is implementation or you can say alternative of toggle function

```html
$('#thiclik').click(function()
{
//toggle alternative 

 function handler1() {
  //alert("first handler for .toggle() called.");
  $("#clickevent").text("Yes");
  $('#thiclik').one("click", handler2);
 }
 function handler2() {
 // alert("second handler for .toggle() called.");
  $("#clickevent").text("No");
  $('#thiclik').one("click", handler1);
 }
 $("#thiclik").one("click", handler1);
});
```

working for me but with little problem when i click first time on click me it not work but on second and third time it works fine.