# Toggle DIV height upon `onClick`

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to toggle the height of a division. I've tried using .animate with a if/else statement. but it would just bounce back. 
The code im now using will hide my division instead of toggling the height. It will trigger when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#content1").toggle(function(){
         $(this).animate({height:'400px'});
   }, function() {
         $(this).animate({height:'200px'});
   });
});
```

I hope someone has the answer because I could nowhere find a answer on google/stackoverflow.

Comment: This version of toggle function is deprecated since version 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9 (not sure though)

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the same?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18206090 a good solution is provided

Comment: Yes, there may be. Let me look ..... ...

Comment: You can use toggleClass and apply the same height in that class

Comment: ^Indeed. That I guess would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use `.animate()` directly to set the height of a div and animate the change each time the div is clicked!

like:

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
    if ( $(this).height() != 50)
          $( this ).animate({ height: 50 }, 1000 );
    else
          $( this ).animate({ height: 100 }, 1000 );
});
```

here's a complete example of it : http://jsfiddle.net/62jcH/3/

Comment: Because I want to animate the height.

Comment: This will work just once, as I wanted to use a toggle.

Comment: Ah!! Then this should do it :D, the event will launch each time the div is clicked!! Check out the answer.. Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can add a data-clicks attribute which will store the number of clicks that can be used to choose the right animation - even/odd.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#content1').data( 'clicks', 0 );
   $("#content1").on( 'click', function() {
      var clicks = +$( this ).data( 'clicks' );
      if( clicks % 2 === 0 ) {
         $(this).animate({height:'400px'});
      } else {
         $(this).animate({height:'200px'});
      }
      $( this ).data( 'clicks', clicks + 1 );
   });
});
```

Alternatively, you could weave a jQuery plugin out of this code and use it instead of the click event.