# toggle CSS within class but only height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have looked everywhere and see plenty examples for what I'm after, but none of them work. I am trying to toggle CSS height onClick. The issue is, the toggle works on first click, but then doesn't work on second. After playing around it either doesn't move at all, or completely toggles the height to 0. Any help would be amazing and appreciated:

```
jQuery( ".tag-see-more" ).click(function() {
     jQuery( ".tagcloud" ).toggle();
     jQuery( ".tagcloud" ).css( {height:260 + "px"});
     jQuery( ".tagcloud" ).css( {height:100 + "%"});
    });
```

Comment: add html or create a fiddle example link of your problem so that we can check and rectify that

Comment: either:- http://jsfiddle.net/44ntLhft/1/   OR  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755601/4248328

Comment: Why don't you toggle a class on the element `jQuery( ".tagcloud" ).toggleClass('visible');`, and add style to that class from css `.tagcloud {height: 260px;} .tagcloud.visible {height: 100%;}`

Comment: there's no need of this statement `jQuery( ".tagcloud" ).toggle();`

Comment: this code works fine! Try putting a document.ready around it.